# Electron and sqlite3 issue after packaging app on windows

Tags: sqlite, electron, node-sqlite3

I'm working on a simple app with electron and sqlite3 database. Everything is working fine until I package the app, I'm getting the following error.
[sqlite3 module not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UW0s.png)

I have tried everything from the old question and answers like,

1. electron-rebuild
2. building from the source

but no luck.

here is my package.json

```
{
  "productName": "Null-Studio-Web-Manager-App",
  "name": "null-studio-web-manager",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Desktop App For Project Cloud CMS",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . null-studios-web-manager-app --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=icon/aslogo1.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Null-Studios-Web-Manager\""
  },
  "author": "ProjectX",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.2.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.11.0",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-builder": "^22.8.0",
    "electron-packager": "^15.0.0"
  }
}
```

I tried to package it by electron packager.
`electron-packager . null-studios-web-manager-app --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=icon/aslogo1.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Null-Studios-Web-Manager\"`

also tried by writing build.js workaround

```
const packager = require("electron-packager");
const rebuild = require("electron-rebuild");

packager({
  dir: "./",
  overwrite: true,
  platform: "win32",
  arch: "ia32",
  prune: true,
  out: "release-builds-folder",
  executableName: "null-studio-web-manager",
  icon: "icon/aslogo1.ico",

  afterCopy: [
    (buildPath, electronVersion, platform, arch, callback) => {
      rebuild
        .rebuild({ buildPath, electronVersion, arch })

        .then(() => callback())

        .catch((error) => callback(error));
    },
  ],
});
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify you get this error while packaging your app, not when you run it?

Comment: everything runs smoothly before packaging it. after packaging when I run .exe I get the error.